# If DropDownList Selected Index Changed, hide gridview rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

How do i call the event dropdownlist.selectedindex.changed on client-side?

Can this be done with javascript/jquery?

What should I include in the markup to enable javascripts?

```
<%@ Page Title="Report" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Report.aspx.cs" Inherits="Report" %>

 <%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Top.aspx" %>
```

I was looking to do something like this

```
IF SelectedValue = 2, Hide Row 1,2,3, and 4
IF SelectedValue = 3, Hide Row 11,21,31, and 41
```

Comment: You'll have to give a bit more information, yes it can be done but what you do want to hide? certain rows, the whole grid?

Comment: if dropdownlist gets changed, then hide gridview rows. i want to do this on client-side, how should the javascript look like?

Comment: @TBohnen just some certain rows.  i believe i included that in the topic title.

Comment: Do you know the row index which you want to hide upon selected Index change ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach the `onchange` event to javascript on your dropdown. Then whenever your `selected Index changes` it will fire and call the javascript `update` method, in which you can hide that particular row.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" onchange="javascript:update();"
```

here is JavaScript code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function update() {
        var ri = 2; // I suppose that you know the Index of Row Which you want to hide
        var grd = document.getElementById('<%= grd.ClientID %>');
        grd.rows[ri].style.display = 'none';
    }

</script>
```

Comment: @Muhammad is it possible to hide dynamic rows? or more like this: hide multiple rows when selectedvalue = 2 and so on.

Comment: @Pod; yes, But you need to pass the RowIndex to your javascript method.

Comment: @muhammad how do i pass a value to the javascript method? is it like c#? update(selectedvalue, rowtohide)?

Comment: Is your dropdwon inside the gridview row, on which Selected value you want to hide row?

Comment: @muhammad no the gridview and dropdown controls are separate

Comment: I can see in your question, you know the rows, which you want to hide. But if you want to pass to JS method, you can pass into command seperate like. update('1,2,3,4,5') and then in JS method, you can split the values in array and iterate and hide rows.

Comment: @muhammad i haven't used javascript before, can you give me an example here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068348/javascript-hide-multiple-gridview-rows