# javascript hide multiple gridview rows

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

DropDownList items

```
a
b
c
```

GridView

```
X | B | C | D | E
a | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
b | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2
c | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3
```

---

When `DropDownList.SelectedItem` = `a`

Hide `GridView.Rows` = `b` & `c`

---

When `DropDownList.SelectedItem` = `b`

Hide `GridView.Rows` = `a` & `c`

---

and so on

---

Anyone know the javascript for doing this client-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the dropdownlist's id is `alpha` and the gridview's `tbl`, you can do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#alpha").change(function(){
    var selVal = $(this).find(":selected").text();   
   var rows =   $("#tbl tr:gt(0)");    
    if (selVal == "ALL") {           
       $("#tbl tr").show();          
    }
    else {        
       var rowToShow = rows.find("td:eq(0)").filter(":contains(" + selVal + ")").closest("tr");
    rows.show().not( rowToShow ).hide();
    }
  });   
});
```

Here is an example in [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/ipoxa4/3/edit)

Comment: @jsang how do you make it show all the rows again? like if there's a dropdownlist.item = "ALL", then reset to show all rows.

Comment: @jsang for some reason it does not work on my project. <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jQuery/1.2.6/jQuery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddmodel").change(function () {
            var selVal = $(this).text();
            alert(selVal);
            var rows = $("#gvtop tr:gt(0)");
            var rowToShow = rows.find("td:eq(3)").filter(":contains(" + selVal + ")").closest("tr");
            rows.show().not(rowToShow).hide();
        });
    });</script>

Comment: @jsang it still doesn't work. i think jquery doesn't work on my end. is this the only line i have to add in the markup? `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: it's too long to be pasted in the comments, i posted here thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069435/jquery-not-working-on-my-asp-page/6069536#6069536

Answer (score 0):

**Sharing a sub-pseudo code below:**

```
Array listFromGridView = [a,b,c];

// get parent dropdownbox and save for future reference
var drop=$("#dropdownBoxID);

drop.bind('click',function(e){ 

// get all element in an array
Array tempList= listFromGridView;

// remove the element which was clicked
// $(this) = the dropdownbox, $(this).val() = selected value
tempList.remove( $(this).val() );

// iterate and hide rows
foreach( element el in tempListView)
// code for hide goes here
});

// Done :-)
```