# jquery not working on my asp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with this for the past few minutes..

```
<%@ Page Title="test" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Top.aspx" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
    <style>
        #pagediv { width: 1500px !important; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddModel").change(function () {
            var selVal = $(this).find(":selected").text();
            var rows = $("#gvTop tr:gt(0)");
            alert(selVal);
            if (selVal == "ALL") {
                $("#gvTop tr").show();
            }
            else {
                var rowToShow = rows.find("td:eq(3)").filter(":contains(" + selVal + ")").closest("tr");
                rows.show().not(rowToShow).hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Still have no idea right now.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddModel" runat="server" DataSourceID="ddmodelsource" DataTextField="Column1" DataValueField="Column1">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvTop" runat="server" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" GridLines="Vertical">
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What is "not working"? Does jquery get loaded (test by doing an alert('jquery loaded'); in your $(document).ready(function...

Can you see it being loaded or any JavaScript errors when testing the page with firebug?

Comment: Does it do something unexpected or is the code not executed at all? Does it work in a minimalized non-ASP HTML-Prototype?

Comment: @Raoul @jm_ adding an alert before `$("#ddModel").change(function () {` works. but the alert() inside that function doesn't work. Am I calling the id's in a wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because in a content page, ASP.NET changes the assigned ID to something else. If you View Source of the page you could see that. So, the alternative is to access the controls using `CssClass`.

For example add a `CssClass` to your `GridView` and `DropDownList`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddModel" runat="server" DataSourceID="ddmodelsource" DataTextField="Column1" DataValueField="Column1" CssClass="dropdown">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:GridView ID="gvTop" runat="server" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" 
        GridLines="Vertical" CssClass="grid">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Now access it from jquery like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown").change(function () {
        var selVal = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        var rows = $(".grid tr:gt(0)");
        alert(selVal);
        if (selVal == "ALL") {
            $(".grid tr").show();
        }
        else {
            var rowToShow = rows.find("td:eq(3)").filter(":contains(" + selVal + ")").closest("tr");
            rows.show().not(rowToShow).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this works just fine, thanks!! i'm just curious, what's the use of # in jquery then if it can't be used like this?

Comment: # in jquery is equivalent to document.getElementById in javascript. the problem is with our asp.net framework(it messes up the ids). you can safely use # in any html control without runat="server". plus jquery is widely used in many other popular frameworks and languages like java, php, ruby....